# Creating JFrame Form in Netbeans does not start the GUI Builder

Tags: user-interface, netbeans, jframe

I feel like the biggest idiot in the world because I can't find this solution anywhere, but it seems like a pretty common problem. So I apologize if there's already a solution out there that I haven't found.

All the tutorials I find on earth say that if I do the following it should work:
Create a Java Application Project > Right click on the package > Go to New > JFrame Form > Name the class > Hit Finish

This is what it opens when I do that.

[image]

I tried looking for a way to just open the GUI builder, but it seems all you have to do is just double click on the file and it should just automatically open it. Also, I noticed that the icon for the "JFrame Form" file that I added is identical to the other java file instead of showing as different in all the tutorials.

Any help would be appreciated.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After some troubleshooting, it appears that it will only work if you don't automatically generate a class when the project is created. It has to be blank so you have the "" package under "Source Packages". Then when you go in and add the new file it actually adds it as a JFrame Form instead of just a regular java file.